# jQuery: Prevent from outputting a line as text

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, erb

I am running this `js.erb` file:

```
<% if params[:type] == "latest" %>$(".folders").find(".latest").addClass("active -red");<% end %>
```

and given that the if statement is true, it does not run this line, instead it just displays it as text in the browser.
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: check its render type in console?

Comment: where is this file in the directory.. you can try checking if this is actually rendered as a JS file.

Comment: it is rendered as js file

Comment: do you have any console error?

Comment: no and that's the weird thing

Comment: It has to be wrapped inside `script` tags

Comment: no, should it be?

Comment: @A.Wolff sir its js.erb so no need to wrap it inside script tag

Comment: @Gugubaight can you just test `$(".folders").find(".latest").addClass("active -red");` in console

Comment: works totally fine

Comment: ah I fixed it. I misspelled the if statement. Sry. Thanks for your help!

Comment: @Gugubaight great

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/126239/discussion-between-uzaif-and-gugubaight).

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
   <% if params[:type] == "latest" %>
      <script>
        $(".folders").find(".latest").addClass("active -red");
      </script>
    <% end %>
```